# Autodesk Platform Services (formerly Forge) embeded Power BI

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to use the custom power BI visual viewCard.pbviz that I downloaded from the Autodeks site. I am adding an urn to the Config field, but I do not have an External ID to add to the Model properties field. How can I get an External ID? Or what values can I use instead of External ID? If I need to make changes in the codes, how can I make changes in which steps? I pull my data with Exchange Data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp2VC.png)

Forge Viewer to view in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DBID or element ID.  The screenshot is from the 1st version of the endymion project, an old sample project.

It's been updated to this, but not formally released:

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-powerbi-tools

Choose the DBID, objectID, elementID or externalID, depending on your source data.

If you are using [Tandem-PowerBi Sample](https://github.com/wallabyway/powerBI-tandem-viewer), you will need to include the URN (since it only works with multi-model).

Since v1, there are updates to improve the authentication mechanism, via a 3-legged refresh [Share App](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-powerbi-tools/tree/develop/services/aps-shares-app) or via the Tandem 2-legged robot/service accounts.